# Kali Linux Installation Stuffing Up

Tags: linux, vmware-workstation, kali-linux, apt

I'm trying to install Kali Linux 2016.1 on my Windows 10 (1607) laptop running VMWare Workstation Pro 12

Laptop specs:

Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4210U CPU @ 1.70GHz 2.40GHz
Installed Memory (RAM): 8.00GB
System Type: 64-bit Operating System, x64-based Processor

Windows edition:

Windows 10 Home Version 1607 OS Build 14393.82

It keeps failing in places so I thought I would ask, as no other tutorials helped :)

Setup:

1. Open VMWare Workstation Pro 12
2. Press CTRL + N to make a new virtual machine
3. Click on typical and click next
4. Click "Installer Disk Image File (ISO)" and browse for my "kali-linux-2016.1-amd64.iso" File, then click next
5. Choose "Linux", Then "Debian 7.x 64-bit", Then Next
6. VM Name: "Kali Linux 2016 64-BIT" Location: "C:\Users*****\Documents\Virtual Machines\Debian 7.x 64-bit", Next
7. Maximum Disk Size: 60.00GB (Yes Its Alot), Store As Single File, Next
8. Customize Hardware, "3172MB Ram" (So Computer Doesn't Freeze During Setup), Close, Finish
9. Power On This Virtual Machine

Installation

1. Install
2. English - English
3. Australia
4. American English
5. Hostname: Kali
6. Domain Name: (Blank)
7. Root Password: **************
8. Re-Enter Password: **************
9. New South Wales
10. Guided - use entire disk
11. SCSI3 (0,0,0) (sda) - 64.4 GB VMware, VMware Virtual S
12. All files in one partition (recommended for new users)
13. Finish partitioning and write changes to disk
14. Yes
15. Use A Network Mirror?: Yes
16. HTTP Proxy: (Blank)
17. The installer failed to access the mirror: Ignore
18. Install the GRUB boot loader to the master boot record?: Yes
19. /dev/sda
20. Installation Finished, Reboot

In VMWARE menu:

1. Click "Kali Linux 2016 64-BIT
2. Click "Edit virtual machine settings"
3. Memory: 6340 MB (Max)
4. OK
5. "Power on this virtual machine"

After boot:

1. GRUB: Kali GNU/Linux
2. Username: root
3. Password: **************
4. (Right-Click) Open Terminal
5. apt-get update

   Reading package lists... Done
6. Upgrade packages

Upgrade

```
$ apt-get upgrade

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded
```

7. Ping google

Ping:

```
$ ping www.google.com
PING www.google.com (58.162.61.242) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 58.164.61.242: icmp_seq=1 ttl=128 time=1383 ms
64 bytes from 58.164.61.242: icmp_seq=3 ttl=128 time=38.8 ms
64 bytes from 58.164.61.242: icmp_seq=4 ttl=128 time=37.7 ms
^C
--- www.google.com ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 3 received, 25% packet loss, time 6019 ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 37.783/486.556/1383.078/633.936 ms, pipe 2
```

If you need any more info, please ask :)

NOTE: I Don't Know Why The Last 3 Statements Stuffed Up.

Comment: so as per your statement the apt-get update is not working?havent u updated sources.list?it would be located under **/etc/apt/sources.list** edit the source with kali linux repositories and provide the command it will work,also clear up the question where you got stucked

Comment: It isn't clear what the problem is here.  The output provided suggests the VM is working perfectly.  Please [edit] and clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its completely fine - apt has updated successfully and upgraded any packages that needed to be. There's just none at all.

This would, in theory be an issue with how kali is set up (lack of properly configured sources.list - [there's a copy here](http://docs.kali.org/faq/kali-sources-list-faq)) or simply there's no updates available.

Double check /etc/apt/sources.list, make sure it has the appropriate values, update so it reflects the changes you made, and upgrade

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone that answered,

I'm sorry that I couldn't be specific, its my first post :)

The way I fixed it was by editing the /etc/apt/sources.list

My problem was that everything in there was commented (#) so, there wasn't any sources.

At first I didn't think of this, until I read through Your comments :)

To fix this:

1. Open Your Kali Linux
2. Open terminal And type:
   nano /etc/apt/sources.list
3. Go to :
   http://docs.kali.org/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories
   and find Your Kali repo (1st Is The Lates 2016.1, Second Is Kali Linux 2.0 etc)
4. Copy what it says, e.g, mine would be:
   deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free
5. Delete everything in:
   /etc/apt/sources.list
   and replace with: rhe repository "deb" link from above
6. Hit CTRL+X, Y, enter to save and exit
7. Done

Comment: That's pretty much what my answer tells you to do. *and* it tells you why. In addition, using title case makes your answers really hard to read.